# Inner-border with transparency affecting element background-repeat

Tags: html, css, sass

I have an element with a background image. On the top and bottom of the element, I want a translucent bar with the image showing underneath. Here is an image of the problem:

[image: Problem]

---

Here is my markup:

```
<div class="section-header art">
    <h1>Art</h1>
</div>
```

Here is my styling (SASS, old  syntax)

```
.section-header.art
    background-image: url(../../img/interpretations__art.bmp)
    background-size: cover
    background-repeat: none
    padding: 5em 0
    box-sizing: border-box
    border-top: 5em solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2)
    border-bottom: 5em solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2)
    h1
        font-size: 4em
        font-family: $type__head
        font-weight: bold
        text-transform: uppercase
        letter-spacing: .4em
        text-align: center
        color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5)
```

---

Just in case you didn't quite notice the issue, the image is repeating in the upper-border, which is not the desired effect.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: FYI: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-origin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`background-repeat: none` it isn't a valid value for background-repeat you should change it to `background-repeat: no-repeat`.

UPDATE: You could resolve this issue by adding a `background-position: 0 -5em;` see an example here: http://sassmeister.com/gist/37d7b2d8a71aa8c879a0

Comment: Thank you, I've made the change, which has stopped the repeat, but still not allowing the background image to be displayed underneath. Here is the up-to-date screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/cAPdddY.png